# creating mobile website using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

I started using Jquery mobile to create a version of my website in mobile. So far its great but I just ran into something yesterday and cannot figure it out. I am pulling in a lot of the code I have already written but it all uses jQuery with the $ in front where JQuery mobile uses jQuery in front of the calls. Is there a way to use both. I have been toying with $.noConflict() but ti no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and check screen size with Modernizr's new media queries test. This has allowed you to keep one page and serve it to various screen sizes without sacrificing quality for mobile/tablet/or desktop.

```js
if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 480px)')) {  
    Modernizr.load('/mobile.js');  
} else if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 768px)')) {  
    Modernizr.load('/tablet.js');  
} else {  
    Modernizr.load('/desktop.js');  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem I am running into is I am using different libraries throughout. For instance, I am using a datepicker.js that is filled with calls like $('#divid').val() but this wont work because the jquery being pulled in is the mobile using jQuery as the function caller. I need to be able to use both because of the different libraries.